# Do you really have to salt the bones, before you burn them?

Tags: supernatural

In the beginning, the Winchesters salt the bones before burning them, but around season 4 I've noticed they don't seem to do the salting as much anymore.

Is it entirely necessary to salt ghost bones, before burning them?

Comment: I always do, but I do know people who don’t.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**As far as the salting mechanics go, the salt is for the purification of the body and preparation for the destruction of the hostile spirit. As to the rationale for why we see it less:**

- In the beginning of the show, they were very detailed with the steps to dealing with their supernatural menaces because the audience was not familiar and growing in knowledge just like the Winchesters were doing.
- As the show progressed they spent less time on those particular details because both the audience knew them and they were less inclined to be on a mission without the necessary ingredients.
- So in most cases, they skip the apparent and easy steps to keep the narrative flow moving. They likely still perform all the steps, they just perform them off-camera.

Comment: +1, The two main Supernatural wikis seem to agree that when dealing with a _body_, salting is necessary for that type of banishment.  I was probably going to post something similar to this soon.

Comment: @izkata only for a body?

Comment: [SupenaturalWiki](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Ghost) mentions a couple instances where the body was dealt with, but there's some remaining object the ghost was attached to that had to _also_ be destroyed.  I don't recall salt being involved with those.  The [Supernatural Wikia](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Ghosts#Weaknesses) also mentions resolving the ghost's issues, and that ghosts can destroy each other.

Answer (score 1):

Mm. Bull. While it might be true, the Winchesters had their memories altered in ep 17 of season 4. I noticed the same thing and went looking for the same answer to the same question, without memories they burned a man's gloves thanks to the ghostfacers site. They did it without salting the gloves and the ghost died.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in most cases the remains are salted then burned. It is the intent of industry to keep things captivating so less screen time is spent with already explained instructions in favor of keeping the suspension of the scene. BUT lazy writing or direction or happenstance will factor in so things like bound objects are only seen burned and must be burned completely to ash (and remember, salting must happen so the spirit cant remove/protect their remains and I suspect iron filings would also work in show lore logic).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in Season 7 Episode 4 they still salt the bones before burning them, there is just less attention drawn to it. They still do it, it just isn't as important to the plot lines anymore.

Answer (score -2):

I noticed that people are very particular on the little thing. So, if there is an actual body to salt, the purification of the body was important but when it comes to a spirit attached to an object unless the object is not able to be set on fire and does not completely burn away then I understand why salting is not needed. The body was already prepped and in some cases cremated.

However, uncle Bobby attaches himself to a flask in the later episodes and can only travel relatively to the flask. So, in this case how is the spirit detached from the object in this case a flask. Is it an exercise to the spirit itself or just destruction of shape and returning in this case a flask back to a pre-manufactured state such as a melted metal state?

I do remember that Sam and Dean seemed to care and show concern for Uncle Bobby's soul and not exercising his soul to turn it into a disgruntled soul or for how long his soul held on to the flask making a frustrated soul beyond saving once it crosses the anger line.

So, my final statement is this, is there a body to salt if yes then salt, if no then object attachment, if yes then burn to smoke with or without salt since no body then no salt. If object does not naturally burn away to smoke leaving nothing physical to attach to then destruction of object is imperative to detach and save a soul or if detachment becomes impossible and Sam and Dean's or any of their merry circle becomes physically or mortally endangered then exercise of said spirit is necessary.

Can any one verify my statement in a proof state or mathematical or "if then" state to be true or if their is a logical issue with my proof serum?

Comment: Could you break this up a bit?

Comment: "Can any one verify my statement..." this is not the place for new questions. If you have a new question please feel free to post it [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)